# Does cannibalism satisfy hunger?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4's [new Survival Mode](https://bethesda.net/#en/events/game/fallout-4s-all-new-survival-mode/2016/03/29/96), you must stay well fed, among other things, to keep in good health. Failing to do so can cause fatigue, temporarily hurt your S.P.E.C.I.A.L. stats, lower immunity, and even cause physical damage.

Does cannibalism satisfy your hunger the same way food in your inventory does, so that you can remain in good health? To be clear, I am asking if cannibalizing a fallen enemy replenishes the 'food' gauge mechanic that is in the new survival mode (not the health bar), or will I still need to pack cooked food before venturing out?

Comment: @TrueDub I'm not sure I agree that it is a duplicate. If cannibalism does indeed provide you food to stay well fed, I think [my answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260694/which-stats-perks-are-more-important-in-new-survival-mode#260783) on that other question should be edited to also provide this bonus. The answer to this question could be **no** and have no bearing on that other question at all. If this is a dupe, all "how does this perk work in the rules of new survival mode" could be interpreted as a duplicate of that one, which I don't agree with.

Comment: Point 6 of your answer directly answers this one - yes, cannibalism satisfies hunger.

Comment: @TrueDub nowhere in my answer do I say that cannibalizing fills up your food gauge. I say that it gives you health. According to the [Bethesda post on new survival mode changes](https://bethesda.net/#en/events/game/fallout-4s-all-new-survival-mode/2016/03/29/96), they're adding a water/food/sleep gauge mechanic, seemingly similar to the ones that were in Fallout: New Vegas's hardcore mode. These are entirely separate from your health bar, and deal with your overall 'wellness'. The lower your wellness, the more ill effects you can suffer, including being more prone to catching infections.

Comment: @TrueDub I've edited my question and added a section to clarify that I am **not** referring to recovering health with cannibalism, instead talking about satisfying the 'hunger' gauge that is introduced in the new survival mode. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Fair enough - will delete my initial comment.

Comment: @king14nyr I've added an answer with a source that indicates cannibalism is very harmful and can easily kill you (and with the new save mechanics you can be stuck). I think you should update your answer on the other question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but with a huge penalty.

Acts of cannibalism give you the "Dark Craving" debuff, which makes it so that **only** human flesh will sate your hunger. This will disappear after you sleep for 24 hours according to [this thread](https://community.bethesda.net/thread/3127).

The comments in the thread titled [Cannibalism: NOT A GOOD SOLUTION FOR HUNGER](https://community.bethesda.net/thread/3718) make it seem to not be worth it, since you cannot "harvest" food to take with you, and must frequently return to areas with humans.

Note that survival mode is currently in early beta, and something like this might well be changed based on the comments of the beta testers.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty intense. And unlike New Vegas, you can't take human remains with you to use later. Thanks for the great answer. The previous answer makes much more sense now knowing about the 'dark craving' debuff.

Answer (score 2):

It recovers hunger but you no longer can eat regular food.